# Solving circular dependency in jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a few circular dependencies in my application. It doesn't affect in production, the app works OK. But now I started to write unit tests using jest and now some of my imports returns `undefined`. And because of that I can't write a single test.

Even when I try to render whole application, there are a few undefined in the imports.

I can't remove these circular dependencies, because it would take a lot of time.

How can I deal with it?

Here are some examples of errors given by Jest

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sensorTypeRenderer')

      4 | import { Renderers, ColumnDescriptionGenerators } from '@components';
    > 6 | import sensorTypeRenderer = Renderers.sensorTypeRenderer;
```

Here's the service is not found because `EventsGroupsStore` is undefined

```
ServiceNotFoundError: Service with "<UNKNOWN_IDENTIFIER>" identifier was not found...

    > 204 |                 return Container.get(EventsGroupsStore);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was not really with the circular dependencies. I just configured aliases incorrectly.

That's how it should be:

```js
    moduleNameMapper: {
        "^@src(.*)": "<rootDir>/src$1",
        "^@tests(.*)": "<rootDir>/tests$1",
        "^@data(.*)": "<rootDir>/tests/mockData$1",
        "^@domain(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/domain$1",
        "^@service(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/service$1",
        "^@utils(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/utils$1",
        "^@view(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/view$1",
        "^.+\\.(css|scss)$": "<rootDir>/tests/styleMock.js",
        "^@resources": "<rootDir>/tests/styleMock.js",
        "^@components(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/components$1",
    },
```

And I just didn't add these `(.*)` and `$1`

Comment: Where you are configuring this? Is it in the `tsconfig.json` or another file?

Comment: @Vitomir I guess the jest config (such as jest.config.json)

Comment: Hey, @AlexisDelrieu. Yes, that was the case. I am currently using the following: `moduleNameMapper: pathsToModuleNameMapper(compilerOptions.paths)` inside my `jest.config.json` from `ts-jest`. It started to work and do not have circular dependency anymore.